# Implement Signing data in django

Tags: c#, python, django, rsa, pkcs#11

I have a code in c#.

```
public string GetSign(string data)
{
var cs = new CspParameters { KeyContainerName = "PaymentTest" };
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cs) { PersistKeyInCsp = false };
rsa.Clear();
rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.FromXmlString("<RSAKeyValue><Modu-
lus>My RSA Private Key</RSAKeyValue>");
byte[] signMain = rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), new
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
string sign = Convert.ToBase64String(signMain);
return sign;
}
```

I want to implement this code in django. In this code , SHA1 is used. I implemented this in python with SHA256 but result is not same.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from base64 import b64decode, b64encode
def sign_data(data, private_key_path):
    from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

    message = b64encode(bytes(data, 'utf8'))
    digest = SHA256.new()
    digest.update(message)    

    private_key = False
    logger.info(private_key_path)

    with open(private_key_path, "r") as key_file:
        private_key = RSA.importKey(key_file.read())

    signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(private_key)
    sig = signer.sign(digest)
    sig = b64encode(sig)
    return sig
```

I changed SHA256 to SHA1 but it gives me error :

```
File "/home/kamiar/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Util/asn1.py", line 211, in encode
    raise ValueError("Trying to DER encode an unknown object")
```

I dont know what is my problem. Can somebody help me ?

Comment: `SHA1` and `SHA256` are two different algorithms. So, results are supposed to be different.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar I see. i changed it to SHA1, but it gives me that error.

Comment: try replacing :`message = b64encode(bytes(data, 'utf8'))`  with : `message = bytes(data, 'utf8')`